# Compact Hausdorf space $\implies$ not the countable union of nowhere dense sets?

Tags: general-topology, baire-category

I can sort of see this intuitively, seeing as it's a similar argument to the Baire Category theorem, but does anyone have a proof I could look at?

Would it suffice to say that every locally compact Hausdorff space is also a Baire space $\implies$ not the countable union of nowhere dense sets?

If so, how about this for a proof?

> Since X is locally compact Hausdorff, it is 
>   homeomorphic to an open subspace of a compact
>   Hausdorff space, say Y. By the Baire Category 
>   Theorem, Y being a compact Hausdorff space
>   implies that Y is a Baire space. Since 
>   open subspaces of Baire spaces are Baire spaces
>   Then X is a Baire Space.

This is under the assumption that a Baire space $\implies$ not the countable union of nowhere dense sets? Unless I misinterpreted the Baire Category Theorem.

Comment: Your conclusion is correct. Baire's Theorem for locally compact Hausdorf spaces is Theorem 10.1 in Dugundji's 'Topology'.

Comment: (contd) [Chapter 11. See also Theorem 10.5]

Comment: More generally, Baire's theorem holds for: **locally compact regular space**, even if not Hausdorff.